# How much energy do you need to heat and melt a sample of ice from -5°C to 50°C?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

A 67.8 g sample of ice initially at -5.00 oC is heated until the final temperature is 50.0 oC.  Calculate the amount of energy gained by the sample. ANSWER IN kJ for sig figs.

The specific heat capacity of ice is 2.09 J/g oC, the specific heat capacity of water is 4.184 J/g oC, the specific heat capacity of steam is 2.03 J/g oC, the ΔHfus = 3.35 x 10^5 J/kg, and the ΔHvap = 2.26 x 10^6 J/kg.

Comment: I need help with finding where you are stuck please.  Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that

- The mass is $m=67.8$ g;
- The specific heat capacity of ice is $c_{\text{ice}}=2.09$ J/(g°C);
- The specific heat capacity of water is $c_{\text{water}}=4.184$ J/(g°C);
- The latent heat of fusion is $\Delta H_{\text{fusion}} = 3.35\cdot10^5$ J/kg$=335$ J/g.

---

1. To go from $T_1=-5$ °C to $T_2=0$ °C you need $c_{\text{ice}}\cdot m\cdot(T_2-T_1)=708.51$ J.
2. To transform from ice to water you need $\Delta H_{\text{fusion}}\cdot m=22713$ J.
3. To go from $T_2=0$ °C to $T_3=50$ °C you need $c_{\text{water}}\cdot m\cdot(T_3-T_2)=14183.76$ J.

---

So, in total you need $708.51$ J+$22713$ J+$7085.1$ J = $37605.27$ J $\approx 37.6$ kJ.

Comment: Hi, welcome to chem.SE. We do not as a community answer homework questions such as the one you have answered here.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried to help. Should I delete my answer ?

Comment: I would say, leave it for future students as a solved example. You can ask them next time if they tried to solve the problem or not. Thanks